# C double to Exponential round error

Tags: c, decimal, exponential

I am trying to convert a double value in to an exponential but I get a rounding error.

```
int main (unsigned int argc, char **argv)
{
    float a=293.17;
    float b=293.10;
    double ULfreq = 2089.555000;
    double upfreq = 0.0;
    long int t = 0;
    long int u = 0;

    upfreq = ULfreq * 1000000.0;

    printf(" %f, upfreq:%22.16E\n", upfreq, upfreq);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code on a 32-bit computer I get the following result:

```
2089555000.000000, upfreq:2.0895549999999998E+09
```

Running it on a 64-bit one gives the correct answer.

Is it possible to make this conversion work on a 32-bit server and how?

Comment: Thank you for not making the code copy&pasteable...

Comment: @glglgl I made an edit on his post, it should be visible for you now or very soon.

Comment: Actually, `2.0895549999999998E+09` (more exactly, in hexadecimal, 0x1.f23050dffffffp30) is the correct result of the double-precision multiplication of `(double)2089.555` by 1000000. The 32-bit computer is correct and the 64-bit computer is doing something strange either during the computation or during the conversion to string

Comment: Ask for more precision in printing, `%.7f` should show you the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not rounding error, but representation feature of floating points. Most short fractions such as 1.1 are infinite series in base 2 (as 1/3 = 0.3333... in base 10). Thus one has to clip it somewhere. When converted back to decimal, 2.08955499999 is what you get.

In the first case you ask printf function to round it to the default precision of %f, which is 6 decimals after the decimal separator. In the second case you are asking 22 digits of precision and get that...

Comment: `base 10` wait, is that two or ten ;-)